When I quickly swipe and change the data in this list, the page stops for 3 minutes
My project architecture is WebView+react, and my application has a VirtualList. When I quickly swipe and change the data in this list, the page stops for 3 minutes
There was no abnormality with this issue. When I switched to another application and returned, the stopped page returned to normal
